# Watch USB connections vendor id, product id and revision

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I'd like to simply watch all devices added and removed from my system and view their USB vendor ID, product ID and revision and other relevant information. How can I do this in Linux? Is there a logfile that I can `tail -f` or does this require something else?

Comment: Is ``dmesg`` detailed enough?

Comment: I don't see any output from tailing /var/log/dmesg. Plug in/remove = nothing.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein `dmesg` does not display all USB events, only ones for which a handler exists and calls `printk()`.

Comment: So is there a way to tail udev for the information?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This information appears in the kernel logs — typically in `/var/log/kern.log`, or `/var/log/syslog`, or some other file (it depends on your syslog configuration, different distributions have different defaults).

If you'd like something pre-filtered, you can add an udev rule. Create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/tkk-log-usb.rules` containing something like:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/tkk-usb-event"
```

The environment of the program is populated with a lot of variables describing the device, including:

- `ACTION` (`add` or `remove`)
- `DEVICE` is a path to the device if you want to access it
- `ID_MODEL_ID` and `ID_VENDOR_ID` contain the model and vendor ID, and `ID_MODEL` and `ID_VENDOR` contain the corresponding text
- `ID_SERIAL` contains the serial number of the device (if available)

Answer (score 13):

You can do that with `udevadm`:

```
udevadm monitor --subsystem-match=usb --property
```

or

```
udevadm monitor --subsystem-match=usb --property --udev
```

to filter only `udev` events. If you want to `grep` for a particular property you will have to un-buffer `udevadm` output (with tools like `stdbuf`, `script`, `unbuffer`...):

```
stdbuf -i 0 -o 0 -e 0 udevadm monitor --subsystem-match=usb --property --udev | grep DEVPATH
```

or

```
script -q /dev/null -c "udevadm monitor --subsystem-match=usb --property --udev" | grep PRODUCT
```

or

```
unbuffer udevadm monitor --subsystem-match=usb --property --udev | grep -E 'ID_VENDOR_ID|ID_MODEL_ID'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to monitor the current plugged USB devices `watch --no-title lsusb` could fit the bill.