# USB port only works when device is plugged prior to boot on Mint 19

Tags: linux, linux-mint, usb-drive

In Linux Mint 19 Tara, my USB port only work  if a device is plugged before  I power on the machine.
If I unplug the device while the computer is on the USB port is no longer usable.I have the problem with any USB device. 
How could I do to solve this problem  ?
my loptop:dell n5010 core i7 
bios model:A15
bios release date:07/19/2011 
sudo dmesg command:

```
setkeycodes e00d <keycode>' to make it known. [ 8699.341368] atkbd serio0: Unknown key pressed (translated set 2, code 0x8d on isa0060/serio0)
```

Comment: Hello and welcome, you did not put enough information in your question, could you read this question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74367/53092 and try to see what event you notice when you unplug and plug back your device.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint 19 "Tara" is the operating system version. Too bad you did not tell anything about your laptop hardware (manufacturer, model). The output of the following commands should be useful in identifying it:

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
sudo dmidecode -s system-version
```

The problem with your laptop seems to be possibly related to power management: this is in large part handled by system firmware (= BIOS or UEFI).

You should check the support webpages of your laptop's hardware vendor to see if there are any firmware updates available, and consider updating to the latest firmware according to the vendor's instructions. The following commands should report the current firmware version:

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date
```

You should also check the kernel message buffer, using the `dmesg` or `sudo dmesg` command (some Linux distributions now require using `sudo` with it, others don't).
Is there anything that looks like a power management or USB-related error message in it?

Try this: view the message buffer, plug in an USB device while Linux is running, and view the message log again. Did plugging in the USB device cause any new messages to be added to the end of the message buffer? Normally there should be some messages resulting from the kernel detecting the new device and loading the driver for it. If there is no new messages at all, then it's very likely a firmware problem: the firmware switches off any unused ports to save battery power, and fails to switch them back on to detect any new devices. Any ACPI-related error messages would also suggest an error in communication between the firmware and the Linux kernel.

Most laptops are less strict in conserving power when receiving power from a charger. Test it also with the power cord connected: it might behave differently then.

Comment: @mehdigrn You should [edit] your question to add information. comments are not read by everybody.